# Ender 4 problem with printer stopping mid print

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-ender-4

I'm looking for suggestions to what might be causing my prints to stop mid print.

I slice with Ultimaker Cura 3.6. Some prints work fine and others randomly stop at different heights for no apparent reason; they are not getting stuck, hung up or lifting. Prints just seems to pause. The quality of the prints are great up to the stopping point. This happens with SD cards and octoprint. Using Hatchbox PLA. All stock Ender 4 parts, no upgrades other then magnetic bed attached to a piece of steel. Bed was manually leveled and auto levels with sensor attached to extruder.

Comment: Add if it comes to a complete standstill or prints without filament, maybe add a link to the G-code, add a link to a visual recording, insert photos, what does the printer LCD say (make photo) or what else you can think of that helps clarify the problem etc.These intermittent problems are very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Since you have octoprint check out this answer to set up serial logging, maybe that will help: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/8047/13883

Comment: One more in the continuing series of "Creality Ender isn't working."  Somehow I get the idea that they are not going to be my first (or tenth) -choice vendor.